# SEO tools say no <h1>, <h2>, etc. when they are loaded by AJAX. Is that a problem for Google?

Tags: seo, google, ajax, heading

All SEO tools I've tested report "No h1" etc. for my most important page. But there are h1, h2 etc. but they are placed in content that is loaded via JavaScript, which is a mandatory property of the Shopsoftware used (Shopware).

I expect that Google will maybe do better than those SEO tools and will probably see the AJAXed content? Will it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure "they" said that h1, etc., are not important, not that you shouldn't use them, unless they were drunk posting. Except using the semantic heading elements will more often gain value for you and not subtract from it. Any statements to the contrary really is drunk posting.

Comment: @rob Suggesting that somebody is "drunk posting" is not kind.  Please read the [code of conduct](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/conduct) and in the future be sure to refrain from unfriendly language.

Comment: @Rob Who said "you shouldn't use them"?

Comment: This is possibly a deficiency in the "SEO tool". However, Google isn't the only search engine and other search engines may not be so good at crawling JS generated content.

Comment: In a more restrained language I think @Rob meant Google doesn't penalize your website because you don't use semantic headings (<h1>...) on the contrary it will favor the websites using those semantic headings.

Comment: @gael understands what I wrote. I call it "drunk posting" because such statements are outrageous and should be called out as written by clueless buffoons. I refuse to be nice to such persons for the sake of being nice and not pointing out blatantly wrong information.

Comment: @Rob I read your comment "drunk posting" as being directed at the SEO sites. You may want to clarify this. I suspect people are assuming you meant this toward the OP. Cheers!!

Comment: Yes. My comment is directed at the SEO sites and not the OP. @closetnoc

Answer (score 3):

Today Google can Crawl your AJAXed content

> Today, as long as you're not blocking Googlebot from crawling your JavaScript or CSS files, we are generally able to render and understand your web pages like modern browsers.

But it recommends following the principles of progressive enhancement.

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether Google is seeing the final rendered page - and thus, whether it is noticing your h1 tags and other elements - by using the [URL Inspection Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289) inside Search Console. (See "View the rendered page" at the bottom of the article for current instructions.) If this tool does show all the content you want indexed, you may wish to contact the authors of the tools to let them know their crawlers aren't up to date with what Google recognizes.